# execute block first before last line of the method

Tags: objective-c, block

The line of code inside blocks in objective c is executed later after executing other lines of code in the same method. 
My query is:

There is a method named :

```
-(NSDictionary*)callingWeatherService{
        NSString *urlString =  @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            // 3
            self.dictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            // 4
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }];


        // 5
        [operation start];
        return self.dictionary;
}
```

But the statement `return self.dictionary;` gets executed first before block execution so dictionary is returned as `nil`;
Is there any solution that statement `return self.dictionary;` is executed only after block execution. I need this approach for a specific purpose.
Don't want to use delegates, I had already used delegates inside afnetworking blocks for getting dictionary data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLSession with NSBlockOperation and queues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198404/nsurlsession-with-nsblockoperation-and-queues)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make function to return after the AFHTTPRequestOperation has done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545164/how-to-make-function-to-return-after-the-afhttprequestoperation-has-done)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - blocks are designed to be performed `asynchronously`, meaning that you never know when they complete. It would be really dumb to change this behavior.

Either use delegates, or use `KVO` assigned to the dictionary variable or `NSNotifications`. If I were you I would definitely use `delegates`.

Comment: "blocks are designed to be performed asynchronously" Not necessarily. Blocks are just runnable things, like functions. They can be run synchronously or asynchronously or whatever.